# ANDROID AutoComplete using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, autocomplete

I have an AutoCompleteTextView in my layout and I want to do an API call which takes the first character entered as a parameter. I do this API call in an AsyncTask to which I pass the first character as a parameter.

What listener should I use on AutoCompleteTextView so that AsyncTask call happens right after the first character is inputted ?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830)

Comment: Fixed this issue by using addTextChangedListener.

Comment: @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.toString().trim().length() == 1) {
                   
                    mAirport = new AsyncTaskAirport(s.toString());
                    mAirport.execute((Void) null);
                }

Comment: you dont need any `TextWatcher` nor `AsyncTask`, see the link i posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue using addTextChangedListener.

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().trim().length() == 1) {
                isFileReceived = false;
                mAirport = new AsyncTaskAirport(s.toString());
                mAirport.execute((Void) null);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link
http://makovkastar.github.io/blog/2014/04/12/android-autocompletetextview-with-suggestions-from-a-web-service/

I achieved the above functionality using shared article.